# Error check: how to extract many columns into data frame and make them into one column in R

Tags: r

I have three columns that want to put into a data frame, and also make it into one column. I already signed each column with a unique ID. And the result I want is two columns, one is column ID, and one is these three column values. These are my original data:

so I want the result like:

```
1 value
2 value
3 value
1 value
2 value
3 value
```

So what I did is:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(cancer)) 
+   for (j in 1:ncol(cancer)){  
+        
+     dtypeID=datatype$dtypeID[datatype$dtype %in% names(cancer)[j]]
+     if (nrow(cancerdata)==0){
+       cancerdata = data.frame(dataID=1,
+                         dtypeID=dtypeID,
+                         value=cancer[i,j]) 
+     } else {
+       
+       lastdataID = max(cancerdata$dataID)
+       dataID=lastdataID+1
+       newline = data.frame(dataID=dataID, 
+                            dtypeID=dtypeID,
+                            value=cancer[i,j])
+       
+       cancerdata=rbind(cancerdata, newline)  
+     } 
+   }
```

But it keep getting me this error:
Error in data.frame(dataID = 1, dtypeID = dtypeID, value = cancer[i, j]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: Can you show an example of the input data (ideally, show the result of `dput(head(cancer))` to give a reproducible result?

Comment: What is the difference between `cancer` and `cancerdata`? From your output it looks like `cancerdata` is an empty data frame.

Comment: And what is your desired output (using these terms rather than the `1 value, 2 value` example you have above)? Please edit it into the question (click the `edit` link) rather than posting it in a comment.

Comment: @DavidRobinson "cancer" is the original data frame, "cancerdata" is the new data frame i want to create.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are trying to do is [melt](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/) the data. Install the `reshape2` package and try:

```
library(reshape2)
cancerdata = melt(cancer, id=c("Gene.symbol", "Pathway.title"))
```

(You can install `reshape2` with `install.packages("reshape2")`).